# More elegant way of parsing my xml document

Tags: java, xml

Currently I recursively parse my xml document. I ask if there are any children nodes and if there are it will iterate through the list of children and all check if those children have children. My base case would be that it doesn't have any more children.  Now the parsing is correct I get a big list of nodes in the correct order.

What I am thinking of doing is making each node its own object.
So entity would be an an object containing index objects, columns objects, etc.
My first way of thinking is iterate through a loop and just have a switch statement checking each node it hits and create objects that will be added to the entity.  I don't think a big switch statement would be correct.

here is a sample of the xml:

```
<ENTITY_DEFS>
    <ENTITY name="WORKORDER">
        <INDEXES>           
            <INDEX name="IDX_WO_1">WORKORDERID</INDEX>
            <INDEX name="IDX_WO_2">WONUM, SITEID</INDEX>
            <INDEX name="IDX_WO_3">ASSETNUM, SITEID</INDEX>
            <INDEX name="IDX_WO_4">LOCATION, SITEID</INDEX>
        </INDEXES>      
        <COLUMNS>
            <COLUMN autokey="Y" autokeyprefix="LOCAL" parentkeycol="PARENTID" uniquekey="Y">WORKORDERID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN displaykey="Y" autokey="Y" autokeyprefix="OFFLN">WONUM</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>PARENTID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>PARENT</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>DESCRIPTION</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>LONGDESCRIPTION</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>LOCATION</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ASSETNUM</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>PERSONGROUP</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>CREWID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>SUPERVISOR</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>LEAD</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>PHONE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>REPORTEDBY</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>REPORTDATE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>STATUS</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>STATUSDATE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>WOPRIORITY</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>WORKTYPE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>FAILURECODE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>PROBLEMCODE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ISTASK</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ORIGRECORDID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ESTDUR</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>OBSERVATION</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>MEASUREMENTVALUE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>TASKID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>SITEID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ORGID</COLUMN>
        </COLUMNS>
        <INIT_ACTION>
            <ACTION>offline/getMyWorkOrderListJson.action</ACTION>
            <ACTION>offline/getMyTaskWorkOrderListJson.action</ACTION>
        </INIT_ACTION>
        <DELTA_ACTION>
            <ACTION>offline/getDeltaMyWorkOrderListJson.action</ACTION>
            <ACTION>offline/getDeltaMyTaskWorkOrderListJson.action</ACTION>
        </DELTA_ACTION>
        <SYNC_ACTIONS transentityname="WORKORDER" transentitykey="WORKORDERID">
            <ACTION name="INSERT" beanname="OfflineDataSyncAction" methodname="addWorkOrder"/>
            <ACTION name="EDIT" beanname="OfflineDataSyncAction" methodname="editWorkOrder"/>
            <ACTION name="INSERT_TASK" beanname="OfflineDataSyncAction" methodname="addTaskWorkOrder"/>
            <ACTION name="UPDATE_STATUS" beanname="OfflineDataSyncAction" methodname="updateWorkOrderStatus"/>
            <ACTION name="UPDATE_TASK" beanname="OfflineDataSyncAction" methodname="updateWorkOrderTask"/>
            <ACTION name="UPDATE_TASK_STATUS" beanname="OfflineDataSyncAction" methodname="updateWorkOrderStatus"/>
            <ACTION name="EMM_FILE_UPLOAD"/>
        </SYNC_ACTIONS>
    </ENTITY>
```

My recursive statement:

```
public void parse(final Document doc,final List<Node> nodelist, final Element el)
{
    final NodeList children = el.getChildNodes();
    for(int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++)
    {
        final Node node = children.item(i);

        if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
        {
            nodelist.add(node);
            parse(doc,nodelist,(Element)node);
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: My choice would be JAXB as the most elegant

Comment: I have parsed the file correctly. I am looking into a more elegant way of creating my entity objects. Anything inside Entity will be an object its self and added to either a list of objects or an object within entity.  I believe I can get by with a switch statement and looping through the whole entire document.  But I feel that is a terrible implementation.

Comment: JAXB does exactly this, and is much easier to code than parsing it by hand.

Comment: Looking at a quick example I believe this will work in my case. The question that I cannot see based off some examples is. If i have <ENTITY name="WORKORDER"> can I get the name attribute?

Comment: Nevermind that is what XMLAttribute is for. Silly me.

Answer (score 1):

More elegant way of doing that would be to pass just the node, since your `nodelist` is traversed through individual object. This way, you would avoid a redundant parameter.

Also, you can make `el` a static String of the `nodename` which you want to capture:

```
public static void parse(Node node) {
        NodeList children = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
            Node currentNode = children.item(i);
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                parse(currentNode);

        }

        if (node.getNodeName().equals(EL_NAME)) {
            System.out.println("This -> " + node.getTextContent());
        }

    }
```

Comment: This was my original idea some what. So if Node.getNodeName().equals("ENTITY") create new entity object but I would have to have like 7 case switch statement. So i wasn't sure if it was something I can avoid.

Comment: @DerekParker aah, so if you need a subset of specific nodes then yes I don't see a way of avoiding it unless you are okay with storing all the traversed nodes to a static collection instance and deal with them later